# How to use composition from another class to set Name?

Tags: java, composition, superclass

I have some of the code here. I am trying to use one class to reference another so I may obtain the first name of the person. I want the firstName in main class to work but IDE mentions the variable isn't found. Will replacing 'first' with 'firstName' work?

Main class:

```
public BasePlusCommissionEmployee( String first, String last, 
            String ssn, double sales, double rate, double salary) {


        cE = new CommissionEmployee( first, last, ssn, sales, rate );
        setBaseSalary( salary );
    }

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        // Trying to get this to work...
        cE.setFirstName(first);
    }
```

SubClass:

```
private String firstName;
public void setFirstName( String first )
    {
        firstName = first;
    }
```

Comment: where do you declare `cE`? show us `BasePlusCommissionEmployee` declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will replacing 'first' with 'firstName' work?

Yes.

```
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    // Trying to get this to work...
    cE.setFirstName(first);
}
```

`firstName` is local variable to this method and a variable with name `first` is not defined within it.

So, if you use `first`, it will be compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want use the setter and getter methods according to the name of the declared variable name. Thus, in your case, if the main class refers the 'first name' as 'first' then better to have setFirst(String first) method declared. if you want to have it declared as 'firstName' then you would want to have it as setFirstName (String firstName).
Also, based on the code you exhibited here, it looks like the main class will going to hold the instance of the CommissionEmployee as 'cE' and it is created using some parameters for which you need setter method in main class.May be avoid declaring those in sub class.